# How can I have 3 if statements in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3 `if` statements for my maths quiz total score and comment:

```
=IF(N12>=9, "That is an excellent score, well done")

=IF(N12<=8, "Not a bad score, good effort, but there is still room for improvement")

=IF(N12<=4, "That is a very disappointing score, revise more for next time")
```

How can I put all of these `if` statements into the one cell where I want the comment to go? Is there a formula which combines all 3?

[Here is a screen shot. the cell which has the number ten in it is n12 (look at the blue box)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfF6X.png)

Comment: Yes you can write a long formula for that ... Or you can use VLOOKUP, Which is how I'd handle it

Comment: i want the comment to be in the comment box and the total score result in n12

Comment: what is VLOOKUP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
=IF(N12<=4,"That is a very disappointing score, revise more for next time",if(N12<=8,"Not a bad score, good effort, but there is still room for improvement",if(N12>=9,"That is an excellent score, well done","error")))
```

But I would put the comments in separate cells and reference those, in fact, you could use index & match much neater to control the limits and return the text...

Edit: 
Added control for 1 :

=IF(N12=1,"Only did one question",IF(N12<=4,"That is a very disappointing score, revise more for next time",IF(N12<=8,"Not a bad score, good effort, but there is still room for improvement",IF(N12>=9,"That is an excellent score, well done","error"))))

Answer (score 0):

You embed one IF inside another.
Here is how:

`=IF(N12>=9, "That is an excellent score, well done", IF(N12<=4, "That is a very disappointing score, revise more for next time", "Not a bad score, good effort, but there is still room for improvement"))`

You do not need to check <=8 because if it is not >=9 an not <=4 then it is between 5 and 8

Comment: it says that there are too many arguments when i put that

Comment: @TristanPilz try mine above and I have tested it to make sure it works. I think that the other answer has a bracket misplaced...

Comment: ok thanks, it works. 1 more thing. how can i make it so that the comment and total score is only filled in when the pupil has actually completed all the questions. i dont want it to say 1 when the pupil has only completed 1 questions.

Comment: @TristanPilz wrap the complete expression to test if the result is <2 or =1  and put blank or whatever, you should see how to do that now.

Comment: i'm sorry. i'm new to excel i don't know what you are talking about

Comment: @TristanPilz see my edit, but you should be able to follow the logic : you teach maths?...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, one bracket was misplaced